# Проектирование реляционной базы данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Например, есть таблица `Car`. Поля - `id`, `type`, `name`. `Type` может быть много разных. И для каждого `Car` по `type` могут быть дополнительные данные. А могут и не быть.

Допустим есть `type big`. Для него нужно указать еще `year`. А для `type light` указать `shop` и `address`. Получается, что сами `Car` должны быть в одной таблице, и все иметь `id`, `type` и `name`. Но в определенных ситуациях они же должны иметь и доп. данные.

**Вариант 1** - добавить все нужные столбцы в таблицу `Car`. Получится, если учесть наш пример - `id`, `type`, `name`, `year`, `shop`, `address`. Но для `type big` поля `shop` и `address` будут всегда пустыми. А для `type light` пустым всегда будет `year`. А если для каждого типа будет по ~10 - 100 доп. полей, то будут получаться записи с ~100 полями, ~90 из которых пусты.

**Вариант 2** - основную инфу хранить в `Car`. Для дополнительной создать `CarBig`, и `CarLight`. Но в этом случае  одним запросом не выберешь сразу все нужные данные, т.к. изначально ведь не знаешь с какой таблицей объединяться.

**Вариант 3** - дизайн как и в варианте 2. Для запросов делать left join для всех дополнительных таблиц. Но если у нас допустим есть `type middle`, которому вообще отдельная таблица не нужна, то для такого случая придется создавать таблицу и ему. `CarMiddle`. И она всегда будет пуста. А если у нас появятся `type middle1...100`, то для всех и таблицы создавать придется. Ну и объединяться со всеми соответственно тоже.

Т.е. идея в том, что есть общие данные и есть дополнительные, которые существуют только для определенных записей. И вот вопрос, как лучше организовать это все. Есть ли еще варианты? И если нет, то какой из существующих самый приемлемый?

Comment: Вариант 2. У Вас же есть поле `type`, по нему и видно изначально с какой таблицей объединять. Вариант 3. Не нужно создавать доп таблицу там, где она не нужна.

Comment: @Sergey, да, по полю type видно, с какой таблицей объединятся, но в таком случае ведь нужен дополнительный запрос. Если это можно сделать в одном запросе, то расскажите, пожалуйста, как. ( как пример - выбрать по id 1. И в этом случае нужно в одном запросе объединиться с нужно таблицей. Вроде как это невозможно.. )

Answer (score 7):

Сталкивался с такой же архитектурой. Суть была в следующем: есть рынок весов, весы бывают разные(автомобильные, железнодорожные, медицинские). В зависимости от подкатегории весов - разные свойства(так например для медицинских добавлялось поле "тип чаши"). Решение было следующее: все свойства(цена деления, предельный вес, тип чаши, типа калибровки и тд) были вынесены в отдельную сущность типа справочника. Далее, от подкатегории(автомобильные, медицинские) идет связь один-много к сущности "свойства подкатегории"(в ней 2 ключа - ID подкатегории и ID свойства). В свою очередь, свойства подкатегории связана один-много с сущностью "данные о товаре", в которой еще лежит форейн от товара и поле "значение"(значение этого самого свойства, которое мы берем из справочника всех свойств)

Answer (score 4):

Возможно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону вертикального хранения аттрибутов.
Для каждого типа данных создать таблицу свойств.
Покажу пример для строк.

Упрощённый вариант:

```
StringProps(CarId, Type, Value)
```

Тогда запрос будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT C.Id, C.Type, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN S.Type='shop' THEN S.Value ENS)shop,
  MAX(CASE WHEN S.Type='address' THEN S.Value ENS)address,
  MAX(CASE WHEN S.Type='year' THEN S.Value ENS)year
FROM Car C
  LEFT JOIN StringProps S ON S.CarId = C.Id
GROUP BY C.Id, C.Type
```

Или если вам нужног конкретное свойство, то так:

```
SELECT C.Id, C.Type, S.Value shop
FROM Car C
  LEFT JOIN StringProps S ON S.CarId = C.Id AND S.Type = 'shop'
```

Есть чуть более сложный вариант, но более надёжный.
Создать две таблицы, свойств и типов свойств.

```
StringProps(CarId, TypeId, Value)
StringDesc(Id, CarType, Name)
```

Тогда запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT C.Id, C.Type, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN SD.Name='shop' THEN S.Value ENS)shop,
  MAX(CASE WHEN SD.Name='address' THEN S.Value ENS)address,
  MAX(CASE WHEN SD.Name='year' THEN S.Value ENS)year
FROM Car C
  LEFT JOIN StringProps S ON S.CarId = C.Id
  LEFT JOIN StringPDesc SD ON SD.CarType = C.Type AND SD.Id = S.TypeId
GROUP BY C.Id, C.Type

SELECT C.Id, C.Type, S.Value shop 
FROM Car C
  LEFT JOIN StringProps S ON S.CarId = C.Id
  LEFT JOIN StringPDesc SD ON SD.CarType = C.Type AND SD.Id = S.TypeId AND SD.Name='shop'
```

Смысл второго подхода в том, что мы не сможем запихать в свойства белиберду. А сможем только те свойства, которые перечислены в StringDesc.Конечно, если создать необходимые внешние ключи.

Подробнее можете почитать [А. Тенцер БД - хранилище объектов](http://www.interface.ru/fset.asp?Url=/misc/hran_01.htm).

Comment: EAV https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model Если это и не тоже самое, но очень похоже. Под другим углом. Более понятно, не смотря на аглицкий. Хотя сложности реализации ни сколько не отменяет. Если Вы пишите StringProps(CarId, Type, Value), то там будет StringProps(CarId, AttributeId, Value) и сразу видно в чём суть. Type сбивает с толку.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам не нужно делать выборку по дополнительным полям, и сами данные потом обрабатываются каким-либо приложением, вы можете собрать эти дополнительные данные в, например, JSON объект и сохранить в поле meta таблицы Car.

```
id, type, name, meta
1, CarBig, CarName, { attr1: value1, attr2: value2}
```

Поле meta может иметь как тип TEXT, так и тип JSON для MySQL 5.7.8 или выше. Во втором случае вы можете производить выборки по полю meta.

Answer (score 0):

В одном запросе можно объединить сколько хочешь таблиц. Где-то уже давал такую подсказку.

```
   select c.*, b.*, l.* --c.id, c.name, c.type, b.year, l.shop, l.address
     from Car c
     left join CarBig b on b.car_id = c.id
     left join CarLight l on l.car_id = c.id
    where c.id = 1
```

получив результат такого запроса смотрим `c.type`:

если он равен `big`, то используем поля `b.*`: `b.year` часть `l.*` не нужна (и по-хорошему там все поля == null)

если `c.type` равен `ligh` то используем `l.*`: `l.shop`, `l.address` часть `b.*` игнорируется (и тоже все поля из этой части == null).

Собирается всё что можно, и потом, исходя из полученного типа, используется только нужное.

Это хорошо работает при не очень большом количестве доп. таблиц и не планируется добавление новых таблиц для новых характеристик.
Если список характеристик большой и будет ещё пополнятся, то обратите внимание на другие ответы.